# Why is this map statement formatted with this syntax?

Tags: java, mapping

I came across this statement while looking over a project and I'm trying to figure out how it works.

```
private Map<String, Map<String, List>> bank;
```

I have some experience with using maps but when I looked at this line I was a bit confused. The project consists of using enumeration objects.

One example of the enumeration objects created would be:

```
a2("Distinct", "adjective", "Familiar. Worked in Java.")
```

Another example is:

```
a3("Distinct", "adjective", "Unique. No duplicates. Clearly different or of a different kind.")
```

I know how the Map works (please correct me if I am wrong). The word, "Distinct", in this case, is being mapped to part of speech (which is mapped to a list containing the definitions of the same word).

The main question I have is, how is this a valid statement, and why is the syntax different than normally creating a map, like this:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Any help would be great, thank you so much.

Comment: The statement you've shown is _not_ creating a `Map`.  It's only declaring a variable.  And it should really be `private Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> bank;` since the lists in the map seem to be lists of strings.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just a clarification, this means that bank variable is the map itself, right?

Comment: A variable (if it's an object type, like `bank` here) can either be null, or refer to an object.  Creating the object is a separate endeavour from making the variable refer to it.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

This is just a map which associates a string to a list of strings. Like `key <-> value1, value2, value3`

To add a value there just use

```
map.computeIfAbsent("key", o->new ArrayList<>()).add("value1");
map.computeIfAbsent("key", o->new ArrayList<>()).add("value2");
map.computeIfAbsent("key", o->new ArrayList<>()).add("value3");
```

If you want to have 3 strings associated, like `"Distinct", "adjective", "Familiar. Worked in Java."` consider using `map of maps`:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String?>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

To put a value there, use the following construction:

```
map.computeIfAbsent("Distinct", k->new HashMap<>()).computeIfAbsent("adjective", k->new ArrayList<>()).add("Familiar. Worked in Java.")
map.computeIfAbsent("Distinct", k->new HashMap<>()).computeIfAbsent("adjective", k->new ArrayList<>()).add("Unique. No duplicates. Clearly different or of a different kind.")
```

See [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) and [Baeldung's how-to](https://www.baeldung.com/java-map-computeifabsent)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; it's definitely more clear now. I'll try adding experimenting with the above code you provided.